# How can i verify srpTupleJson variable data is in 'list' or 'string' using protractor?

Tags: list, protractor

Html clode :

```
  <script>
            srpTupleJson = [{"name":"Praveen Mishra","title":"B.Tech in Computers Science with 1 year exp. in python\/django","isPremium":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNew":false,"employement":{"current":{"designation":"Python Developer","organization":"Freelancing  Project"},"previous":{"designation":"Python Developer","organization":"Derwent Technologies Pvt
</script>
```

How can i verify srpTupleJson data is in list or string using protractor.

Comment: Do you want to check if `srpTupleJson` variable is defined in a `script` element on a page? Or, do you want to also check it's type?..

Comment: @alecxe I want to check its type ... If it is a list then test case should pass..

Comment: This is not what protractor is meant to do. Protractor is meant to test the DOM structure of your document. With it, you can ensure that clicking on a button behaves the way you expect it to. Protractor does not have east access to the internal state of the application. It sounds like you will be better off using Karma to run unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to protractor, it is related to javascript.

You can use `typeof`. For example:

```
if( typeof someVariable === 'object' ) {
    /* Do something */
}else if(typeof someVariable === 'string' ){
    /* Do something */
}
```